# How to run a post-install script after individual execution of "npm install <package>"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, npm-scripts

I am maintaining the following directory structure:

```
/home/user/Desktop/
                 |-- app/
                 |      |-- package.json
                 |      `-- server.js
                 |-- node/
                 |      |-- bin/
                 |      |      |-- node
                 |      |      `-- npm
                 |      |-- include/
                 |      |-- lib/
                 |      `-- share/
                 |
                 `-- npm.sh
```

I want all my locally installed node modules reside in the directory **`node`**. That is, if I run `npm install` inside the directory `app`, initially it'll install the modules inside the current directory (`app`) and then move the `node_modules` folder to the external directory called `node`. For this purpose I've written a script `npm.sh` and placed the `mv` (move) command inside the `postinstall` script of `package.json`.

These are the files `npm.sh` and `package.json`.

content of **`npm.sh`**:

```
#/bin/bash

export PATH=/home/user/Desktop/node/bin:$PATH
export NODE_PATH=/home/user/Desktop/node/node_modules
export NODE_MODULE_ROOT=/home/user/Desktop/node
/bin/bash
```

content of **`app/package.json`**:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "mv node_modules $NODE_MODULE_ROOT",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1"
  }
}
```

But the problem is: when I do `./npm.sh && cd app && npm install`, everything works as intended. But when I do `npm install jwt-simple`, the `postinstall` script is not getting executed.

Is there a way to make it work for individual `npm install <package>` ? Or is there any better way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [npm hook scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts#hook-scripts) to do something after package is installed.

Create `node_modules/.hooks/postinstall` executable and it will be run also after `npm install <package>`.

**NOTE:** I have noticed problems with npm hook scripts between npm version 5.1.0 until 6.0.1. So if you have problems with hooks, check your npm version and upgrade if necessary.

Comment: The script will be run with the working directory set to the package location. Use $INIT_CWD in your script to get the path of the directory from where the `npm install <package>` was run.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Windows (I just tried it), because the hook-script filename has to exactly be "postinstall", which makes Windows unable to recognize it as an executable (it just errors with `Exit status 1`, and doesn't run the file, regardless of if I use a (previously) `.exe`, `.js`, `.bat`, or `.cmd` file).

Anyone know of a way to get this approach to work on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else stumbling here npm doesn't run pre/postinstall in the package.json when installing a specific package. You can check here for reference, https://npm.community/t/preinstall-npm-hook-doesnt-execute-when-installing-a-specific-package/2505. Not sure if there is a way around it but I've been looking too.

Answer (score 2):

I can't write a comment yet, since I'm a new user, but I wanted to elaborate on [Niko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51155609/17717884).

It seems the [Hook Scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#hook-scripts) functionality has been [removed](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2692) [starting with **npm v7.X**](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2762).

So, in order to use a `node_modules/.hooks/postinstall` hook, running **npm v6.X** would be the best bet.

Plus, as pointed out in the comments, there's a catch: Hook Scripts won't work out of the box on Windows, because it won't be able to recognize the file as being executable since it lacks a file extension.

A *not so pretty* workaround is to create, for instance, a `postinstall.cmd` and soft (or hard `/H`) linking it with `mklink postinstall postinstall.cmd`

This will ensure that Windows recognizes the file as a `.cmd` executable to correctly run it.